# How to get and set session variable using JQuery in html?

Tags: jquery

I have a openpopup() to open a popup contains two button yes and no. if visitor click yes then the pop up should be disabled throughout its session.So idea is to set a session variable on click of 'yes' button and get in openpopup() to check if visitor clicked 'yes'.
onclick 'yes'

```
    <input type='button' onclick='abc'>
    <script>
    function abc() {
        $("#divid").hide();
        if (!localStorage['visited']) {
            openpopup();
            localStorage['visited'] = "yes";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Issue : I need to set expiration of local storage. plz help

Comment: I would suggest to use SessionStorage instead of LocalStorage, that way your variables will be "cleaned" after every session. LocalStorage is persistent which means it will never be cleaned up unless you handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, instead of storing just a string, store an object in `localStorage`, like so:

```
localStorage['visited'] = { value: true, expiration: sometimestamp };
```

Then of course when checking the value of `localStorage['visited']` later, you must verify that the expiration timestamp is still valid:

```
var v = localStorage['visited'];
if (v.expiration < new Date().getTime())
{
   ...
}
```